# I want the <div class="div-global-tab> to open up to the right of the "Global" text when i hover over it

Tags: javascript, html, css

At the moment the div opens up to the bottom of the "Global" text, but i need it to open up to the right of it, like a small box.

```css
.div-global-tab{ /* div global */
    display: none;
}
  
#global:hover .div-global-tab{ /* li ul global */
    display: block;
}
```

```html
                        <li id="global">
                            <a href="#">Global</a>
                            <div class="div-global-tab">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">North America</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">South America</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Climate Change</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Global Disasters</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">The Future</a></li>
                                    <br>
                                    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```css
.div-global-tab{ /* div global */
    display: none;
}
  
#global:hover .div-global-tab{ /* li ul global */
    display: block;
    background-color: #c5c5c5;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul > li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#global {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: top;
}
```

```html
<li id="global">
                            <a href="#">Global</a>
                            <div class="div-global-tab">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">North America</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">South America</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Climate Change</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Global Disasters</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">The Future</a></li>
                                    <br>
                                    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

EDIT: using flex will allow subsequent lists to be displayed next to the previous one

EDIT 2: add styling

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `inline-block` and `position absolute`. This makes it that it always come next to you `a` element.

```css
.div-global-tab{ /* div global */
    display: none;
}
  
#global:hover .div-global-tab{ /* li ul global */
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<li id="global">
  <a href="#">Global</a>
  <div class="div-global-tab">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">North America</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">South America</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Climate Change</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Global Disasters</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">The Future</a></li>
          <br>
          <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```